# Trouble with API pull of XML into Google Sheet with App Script

Tags: javascript, xml, google-apps-script, google-sheets

What I am trying to accomplish seems like it should be very simple, but I am beating my head against a wall.  I have the API call working.  I can pull the data into App Script, my problem is manipulating it into a table.  This is the XML:

```
<advanced_computer_search>
    <id>6</id>
    <name>_Java-Version</name>
    <view_as>Standard Web Page</view_as>
    <sort_1/>
    <sort_2/>
    <sort_3/>
    <criteria>
        <size>0</size>
    </criteria>
    <display_fields>
        <size>4</size>
        <display_field>
            <name>Computer Name</name>
        </display_field>
        <display_field>
            <name>Operating System Version</name>
        </display_field>
        <display_field>
            <name>Java Version</name>
        </display_field>
        <display_field>
            <name>Last Check-in</name>
        </display_field>
    </display_fields>
    <computers>
        <size>48</size>
        <computer>
            <name>TEST-MBP-CWP</name>
            <udid>103481203840912384098213409</udid>
            <id>14</id>
            <Computer_Name>TEST-MBP-CWP</Computer_Name>
            <Operating_System_Version>12.6.0</Operating_System_Version>
            <Java_Version/>
            <Last_Check_in>2022-11-10 10:42:29</Last_Check_in>
        </computer>
        <computer>
            <name>test-mbp (3)</name>
            <udid>103481203840912384098213407</udid>
            <id>22</id>
            <Computer_Name>test-mbp (3)</Computer_Name>
            <Operating_System_Version>12.6.0</Operating_System_Version>
            <Java_Version/>
            <Last_Check_in>2022-11-09 13:32:15</Last_Check_in>
        </computer>
        <computer>
            <name>test-mbp19</name>
            <udid>103481203840912384098213408</udid>
            <id>24</id>
            <Computer_Name>test-mbp19</Computer_Name>
            <Operating_System_Version>11.7.0</Operating_System_Version>
            <Java_Version>1.8.0_201</Java_Version>
            <Last_Check_in>2022-10-18 13:18:26</Last_Check_in>
        </computer>
        <computer>
            <name>TEST-2019-MBP-I5</name>
            <udid>103481203840912384098213406</udid>
            <id>43</id>
            <Computer_Name>TEST-2019-MBP-I5</Computer_Name>
            <Operating_System_Version>12.5.1</Operating_System_Version>
            <Java_Version/>
            <Last_Check_in>2022-11-09 18:30:29</Last_Check_in>
        </computer>
    </computers>
    <site>
        <id>-1</id>
        <name>None</name>
    </site>
</advanced_computer_search>
```

What I am looking to get is a table for computers with the top row:
(name, udid, id, Computer_Name, Operating_System_Version, Java_Version, Last_Check_in)

Then the subsequent x number of rows would be all the data.

```
//Query jamf 
  var url = '<MY URL)>;
  var jamfXml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
            "Authorization": "MY AUTH",
            "Content-Type": "application/xml"
        },
    }).getContentText();
 //console.log(jamfXml);

  var document = XmlService.parse(jamfXml);
  var computers = document.getRootElement().getChildren("computers");
  //console.log(computers);
  var computersLength = document.getRootElement().getChild("computers").getChild("size").getValue();
```

I would think there would be a dynamic way to get the element labels into the top row so the same script could be reused without needing too hard code the column headers or number of columns.  Then put the dynamic data in the following rows.  I just cannot figure out how.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

What I tried is various versions of the code above with 2 to 3 nested foreach loops. Similar to this:

```
var listComputers=[]
  
  console.log(computers.length)
  //console.log(computers[0][0].length)

  computers.forEach(function(item){
    //console.log(item.getValue());
    var computer=[]
    item.getChildren().forEach(function(details){
      //console.log(details.getValue());
      details.getChildren().forEach(function(moreDetails){
        //console.log(moreDetails.getValue());
        computer.push(moreDetails.getValue());
      })
    })
    listComputers.push(computer);
  })

  console.log(listComputers);
  console.log(listComputers[0].length);
  console.log(listComputers[0][1].length);
  console.log(listComputers[0][1]);
```

Writing to the sheet is not included, I have been able to do that but the data ends up all concatenated into a single cell.

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, I thought that `var computer = []` and `listComputers.push(computer);` are required to be put into the loop of `item.getChildren().forEach(function (details) {,,,})`.
- And also, in your script, `<size>48</size>` is also retrieved.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```js
computers.forEach(function(item){
  //console.log(item.getValue());
  var computer=[]
  item.getChildren().forEach(function(details){
    //console.log(details.getValue());
    details.getChildren().forEach(function(moreDetails){
      //console.log(moreDetails.getValue());
      computer.push(moreDetails.getValue());
    })
  })
  listComputers.push(computer);
})
```

##### To:

```js
computers.forEach(function (item) {
  item.getChildren().forEach(function (details) {
    if (details.getName() == "computer") {
      var computer = []
      details.getChildren().forEach(function (moreDetails) {
        computer.push(moreDetails.getValue());
      });
      listComputers.push(computer);
    }
  });
});
```

- By this modification, each value of `<computer>` tag is retrieved in an array.

#### Note:

- If the order of tags in `<computer>` tag might be changed, I thought that the following sample script might be also useful. In this sample, the order of header titles is constant. And also, in this sample script, it supposes that `jamfXml` is your showing sample XML data. Please be careful about this.

  ```js
  var url = '<MY URL)>';
  var jamfXml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
            "Authorization": "MY AUTH",
            "Content-Type": "application/xml"
        },
    }).getContentText();
  var headers = ["name", "udid", "id", "Computer_Name", "Operating_System_Version", "Java_Version", "Last_Check_in"];
  var document = XmlService.parse(jamfXml);
  var root = document.getRootElement();
  var ns = root.getNamespace();
  var values = root.getChild("computers", ns).getChildren("computer", ns).map(e => headers.map(h => e.getChild(h, ns).getValue() || ""));
  console.log(values);
  ```

#### References:

- [XML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)